# what wrong with my AWS Lambda creating project?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, superclass

Hey so I downloaed all the tools for AWS toolkit required for eclipse, and new im trying to create A new AWS lambda project and I give it a package, project name and  change input type to custom then provide String for input type and out Type, after loading it creates a project but comes back with errors so, please can some tell my what's wrong??

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) // error is this hanleRequest it states Multiple markers at this line
    - The method handleRequest(String, Context) of type LambdaFunctionHandler must override a superclass method
    - implements   {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return null;
    }

}


}
```

Comment: my lambda function will not run due to ..... {
  "errorMessage": "Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tThe method handleRequest(String, Context) of type LambdaFunctionHandler must override a superclass method\n",
  "errorType": "java.lang.Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:9)",
    "com.amazonaws.lambda.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:1)"
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

The AWS documentation is outdated.

You need to implement a different interface.

Passing a map:

```
public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,Object>,String>
```

Passing into a custom POJO object:

```
public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<CustomRequest,CustomResponse> {
```

Consuming a stream:

```
public class MyHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
```

Make sure to grab the right dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I developed a [sample application](https://github.com/udoheld/aws-lambda-hello-log) implementing each of the interfaces. You can just clone it from [github](https://github.com/udoheld/aws-lambda-hello-log). One of the handlers will print out all available environment variables as well.

Lambda expects JSON as input.